# Compare files to get string before special character

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to evaluate two different files (.tf files) to check if the resource names are the same in a bash script.
I know that in those files resources are declared as such:

```
resource "service_name" "resource_name" {
 #resource config
}
```

One approach would be something like:

```sh
while read line
do
    if word_file1 == "resource"; then
        #save string in array1 before "{" character
    fi
    while read line
    do
        if word_file2 == "resource"; then
            #save string in array2 before "{" character
            if array1 == array2; then
                break
            else 
                # write diff to another file, including all config 
                # info between {} for the missing or different resource
            fi
        fi
    done < filename2
done < filename1
```

**From a test file (file1) an example input would be:**

```
resource "service_name" "resource_name_AA" {
 #resource config
 # policy_config = << POLICY
 { 
     policy_definition

 } POLICY
}
```

**From a test file (file2) an example input would be:**

```
resource "service_name" "resource_name_AA" {
 #resource config
 # policy_config = << POLICY
 { 
     policy_definition

 } POLICY
}

resource "service_name" "resource_name_BB" {
 #resource config
 # policy_config = << POLICY
 { 
     policy_definition

 } POLICY
}
```

**The desired output would be (diff_file):**

```
resource "service_name" "resource_name_BB" {
 #resource config
 # policy_config = << POLICY
 { 
     policy_definition

 } POLICY
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to compare two different files and check if string "resource_name" is same or not ?

Comment: Yes, the purpose is to evaluate if the resources are the same for both files. If not, I would like to get a diff file with the resources that differ between files. 
Since the files are very big, I try to check where "resource" appears to pinpoint the line, but my real goal is understanding if "resource_name" is the same. If it differs, I want to be able to get all config data including the resource name to a diff file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do the job. I guess as per the code you showed, the contents of the resource also need to to printed in cases of mismatch. If only difference needs to be pointed out, `diff` is better and enough. Anyways I still like writing `awk`(still a bit new, learning) scripts, so wrote one.

```
#! /bin/bash

awk '{
    if (FNR == NR)
    {
        if ($1 == "resource")
            resource_name=$3
        else
            contents[resource_name]=contents[resource_name]"\n"

        contents[resource_name]=contents[resource_name]$0
    }
    else
    {
        if (($1 == "}") && (flag == 1))
        {
            flag=0
            next
        }
        else
        if (($1 == "resource") && (contents[$3] != ""))
        {
            flag=1
            contents[$3]=""
            next
        }   
        
        if (flag == 1)
            next
        
        print
    }
} 
END {
    for (resource in contents) 
    {
        if (contents[resource] != "")
            print contents[resource]
    }
}
' file2 file1 > otherfile
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```
#! /bin/bash

awk '{
    if (FNR == NR)
    {
        if ($1 == "resource")
            resource_name=$3
        else
            contents[resource_name]=contents[resource_name]"\n"

        contents[resource_name]=contents[resource_name]$0
    }
    else
    {
        if (($1 == "}") && (flag == 1))
        {
            flag=0
            next
        }
        else
        if (($1 == "resource") && (contents[$3] == ""))
        {
            flag=1
            contents[$3]=""
            next
        }   

        if (flag == 1)
            next

        print
    }
}' file1 file2 > same_resources
```

---

## UPDATE-2:

```
#! /bin/bash

awk '{
    if (FNR == NR)
    {
        if ($1 == "resource")
            resource_name=$3
        else
            contents[resource_name]=contents[resource_name]"\n"

        contents[resource_name]=contents[resource_name]$0
    }
    else
    {
        if ($1 == "resource")
        {
            if (flag == 1)
            {
                flag=0
            }
            if (contents[$3] != "") 
            {
                flag=1
                contents[$3]=""
            }
        }   

        if (flag == 1)
            next

        print
    }
} 
END {
    for (resource in contents) 
    {
        if (contents[resource] != "")
            print contents[resource]
    }
}' file2 file1 > someotherfile
```

Comment: Although it also works in the way that the diff info is listed in a separate file, it does not retrieve the content for the configuration of the resources. It is something I am still struggling with.

Comment: @MárciaLima you want the resources that are not common to both files listed into another file along with the contents in `{..}`?

Comment: The above `awk` script would list all resource mismatch along with their config in `{}` in a different file.

Comment: Actually, I have tested it again and it does grab the info between {...}, but it is merging the info on both files instead of doing this just for the different content between both files.

Comment: @MárciaLima, the above scripts just compares on the basis of "resource_name". If there is any resource name that is not common to both the files, it send it to `otherfile`. If in case that's that exactly what you want, could you post 2-3 original looking resources from each file and how you want the output?

Comment: if the `resource_name` is the same between both files it will still write the config information into the `otherfile`, just not the record with `resource`. I have used test files with different `resource_name` between themselves and a bunch of config info between `{...}` and the output file is a merge of both but with the common `resource`records deleted.

Comment: @MárciaLima, I have updated my answer. Before I thought yoy wanted the uncommon records. Check out the updated answer if it helps.

Comment: your solution was absolutely correct in the way that allowed me to have the uncommon resources from different files. The only issue with your solution was that if the `resource_name`matched on both files it would still print out the config on `otherfile`, just not the matching records which is still not desireable because I only want the `resource_name` and respective configs of the uncommon resources on the `otherfile`. Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly before.

Comment: @MárciaLima, Maybe due to language gap, I can't understand you correctly. It would be great if you could update your questin to contain some sample input and sample output instead.

Comment: Mihir, I have updated the question with the desired output. Maybe it will be more helpful this way. Thank you for your support so far!

Comment: @MárciaLima, I have updated my answer, this time it should probably work fine now. It should redirect the desired output to `someotherfile`. In my first script I assumed that the contents inside `{…}` won't contain additional `{}`. Most probably this time the checking is more accurate.

Comment: OMG! Works perfectly now! :)
Thank you so much, @Mihir!

Comment: @MárciaLima glad it worked, though be sure that if there are any nested resources, like a resource within block(`{}`) of another resource, this script may show undesirable output. In that case we need to stack up `{` and pop them out accordingly(which adds unnecessary complexity) . But if this solution solves the problem, no need to change anything.

Answer (score 2):

I think I would try to keep it simpler than that:

```
 grep 'resource' file1 > file1_resources.txt 
 grep 'resource' file2 > file2_resources.txt 
 diff file{1,2}_resources.txt
```

if the word "resource" shows up in different contexts, then you could use a regexp grep instead:

```
egrep "resource.*\{" fileX
```

Comment: Definitely simpler is better.  In this case,  I think your answer is on the right track.  I would consider adding sort to your answer so if the resources are declared out of order, the diff output would be easier to reconcile.

Comment: Thanks for your support, I am closer to a solution than before! However, the diff output file is also storing other characters within the file that are not very useful for my use case like ">" and others numbers. Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: Instead of diff, I used comm -13 file1 file2 > out_file and it produced the desired output (no gibberish text from diff). Thanks!